# Setting authorizationExceptionRetryInterval for Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

Anyone know how to set the new property: authorizationExceptionRetryInterval without creating the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to say...

```java
@Component
class ContainerFactoryCustomizer {

    ContainerFactoryCustomizer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?, ?> factory) {
        factory.setContainerCustomizer(
                container -> container.getContainerProperties()
                        .setAuthorizationExceptionRetryInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(10L)));
    }

}
```

But that doesn't work, [due to a bug (the container customizer is not set up)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1376).

Here is a work-around:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So60054097Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So60054097Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so60054097", topics = "so60054097", autoStartup = "false")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so60054097").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
        return args -> {
            MessageListenerContainer container = registry.getListenerContainer("so60054097");
            container.getContainerProperties()
                    .setAuthorizationExceptionRetryInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(10L));
            container.start();
        };
    }
}
```

(Set `autoStartup` to false; fix the property and start the container).

Comment: Great, thanks! Might wait for the fix for issue 1376