# Recovering Kafka clients (consumers/producers) after they went down

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

At the company i work with we use `Spring for Kafka` without authentication and lately we did some experiments to setup the security in Kafka and we enabled authentication for a brief moment which cause a crush in all our consumers/producers within our microservices ! (the microservices stayed up)

The exception :

```
Authorization Exception and no authorizationExceptionRetryInterval set

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group: foo-group
```

after some researchs we found out that this is the expected behavior by kafka clients and we needed to set the `authorizationExceptionRetryInterval` property

[**public void setAuthorizationExceptionRetryInterval​(java.time.Duration authorizationExceptionRetryInterval)**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerProperties.html#setAuthorizationExceptionRetryInterval(java.time.Duration))

> Set the interval between retries after AuthorizationException is
> thrown by KafkaConsumer. By default the field is null and retries are
> disabled. In such case the container will be stopped. The interval
> must be less than max.poll.interval.ms consumer property.

Here is some other useful links

[Setting authorizationExceptionRetryInterval for Spring Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054097/setting-authorizationexceptionretryinterval-for-spring-kafka)

[Why does the spring KafkaConsumer suspend all consumption from n topics when one fails to authorize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719314/why-does-the-spring-kafkaconsumer-suspend-all-consumption-from-n-topics-when-one)

What i want to know is :

1. Is a failed authentication the only case when
   consumers/producers goes down ?
2. If there are some other cases, how to make sure that our
   consumers/producers recover without human intervention (restarting
   the microservices) ? In other word how to check if the
   consumers/producers are up and restart them otherwise ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Containers are stopped only under the following circumstances:

- `AuthorizationException` with no `authorizationExceptionRetryInterval`
- `NoOffsetForPartitionException` - thrown when `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` is not `earliest` or `latest` and there is no existing offset for a partition with this consumer group.
- `FencedInstanceIdException` - using transactions and static group members (meaning some other instance is using this instance id).
- `StopAfterFenceException` - when `stopContainerWhenFenced` is true (default false) - only applies with transactions
- Any `Error` (such as OOME)

Comment: thanks @Gary but what are your suggestions to recover them after they stopped (if the microservice they are running in still up) ?

Comment: You can add an `ApplicationEventListener` bean or `@EventListener` method and listen for `ConsumerStoppedEvent`s or `ContainerStoppedEvent`s and shut down the entire service if that's what you want. Or you can add logic to try restarting the containers periodically. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#events and https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafkalistener-lifecycle

Comment: thanks Gary i will try some of these suggestions