# How to disable container stop when kafka error spring kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When I have authentication error on my kafka broker, the application drops the container.

Is there any way to disable this behavior?

I'm using KafkaListener

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.consumer.topic}", concurrency = "${listen.concurrency:3}")
    public void topicListener(Product<String> message) {
        getLogger().info("message consumed");
    }
```

Let me know if I need to post other settings..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recovering Kafka clients (consumers/producers) after they went down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66519618/recovering-kafka-clients-consumers-producers-after-they-went-down)

Answer (score 0):

See `authorizationExceptionRetryInterval` option on the `ConsumerProperties`:

```
/**
 * Set the interval between retries after {@code AuthorizationException} is thrown
 * by {@code KafkaConsumer}. By default the field is null and retries are disabled.
 * In such case the container will be stopped.
 *
 * The interval must be less than {@code max.poll.interval.ms} consumer property.
 *
 * @param authorizationExceptionRetryInterval the duration between retries
 * @since 2.3.5
 */
public void setAuthorizationExceptionRetryInterval(Duration authorizationExceptionRetryInterval) {
```

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafka-container

> By default, no interval is configured - authorization errors are considered fatal, which causes the container to stop.